# How do You Find the Number of Places After the Decimal Point with BigDecimal?

Tags: java, android, math, bigdecimal

I'm trying to use BigDecimals to calculate something and then round to 5 decimal places if it has more than that. How can I do this?

Would scale() work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already crawl through JavaDoc, especially the function [precision()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#precision%28%29)?

And this here might be a direct solution which makes it needless to check the precision first:

```
yournumber.round(new MathContext(5, HALF_UP));
```

And after that use stripTrailingZeros()  (thx to @GregKopff)

Comment: I've tried that, but if (for example) the number is 1, it says 1.00000.

Comment: Then also use `stripTrailingZeros()`.

Comment: It's always a good idea to make a proof, also for you to show us what's going wrong. Here the final solution: http://pastebin.com/26Udw915

Comment: Thank  you, the number.round and stripTrailingZeroes() part worked.